# Private two dimensional array in OpenMP

Tags: c++, openmp

As far as I've found in number of sources, when passing an array into an OpenMP control block as `private`, every thread should make it's own copy of this array. However, I've seen different behavior of this in a piece of my code with the following structure:

```
int row, col;
int s[9][9];
omp_set_num_threads(9);
#pragma omp parallel for firstprivate(s)
    for (int val = 1; val < 10; val++) {                                        
        s[row][col] = val;  
        bool b = solve(s, row + col / 9, (col + 1) % 9);
        if (b) {
            //do stuff
        }   
    }
```

where function `solve()` does modify the variable `s`, but does not touch any global variables.

However, I've found out, that the modification of variable `s` by routine solve (for completeness included at the bottom), affects the variable `s` in all other threads as well.

Is this an issue with two dimensional array or am I overlooking something basic?

Routine `solve()`:

```
bool solve(int s[9][9], int row, int col) { 
    while(s[row][col] != 0) {
        col = (col + 1) % 9;
        row = row + col / 8;
        if(row == 9)        
            return true;
    }   

    for (int val = 1; val < 10; val++) {
        if (isPossible(s,row,col,val)){
            s[row][col] = val;
            if (solve(s, row + col / 9, (col + 1) % 9))
                return true;
            s[row][col] = 0;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: It's fine to post this as follow-up question to your previous one, but you must post an independent [mcve] for this question again. I highly suspect `s` is not what you tell us (and you think) it is.

Comment: You are right, I've already located the problem - it was that `s` was an argument of a function, in which this piece of code was written and therefore it was viewed by compiler as an argument the whole time. I solved this problem by copying s into auxiliary array in the function and then using this array in parallel code.